# Vimeo autoplay and transparency

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an embedded iframe from Vimeo autoplay in all browsers and with the transparency mode turn on. It seems I can only choose the one or the other?

I tried messing around with the parameters from [this](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001494447-Using-Player-Parameters) link, but nothing seems to work. Either it autoplays with a white background or it doesn't autoplay with no background.

```
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe 
src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/336448323? 
autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" 
style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" 
frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>   </div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

Anyone solved this before?

Comment: Have you tried looking into CSS for transparency, or using a background with `rgba`( A is the alpha or transparency channel)

Comment: Yes and since it's and iframe and i cant target the css. It must be some parameters